# How to deploy web filtering in iOS using mobile Device Management?

Tags: ios, iphone, server, mdm, ipcu

I am doing **mobile device management** implementation and quite successfully sending commands now thanks to the answers I got in this site.I have one major thing left and that is `web content filtering`.I went through the **configuration Profile** [Web Content Filter Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) and found that we can `blacklist and whiteList` the urls.Also I went through [this](http://www.speirs.org/blog/2013/9/18/web-filtering-in-ios-7.html) and came to know that we can do it using a Mobile Device Management server.The problem I am getting is that how should it can be done.

I am using **iPhone Configuration Utility** for my MDM installation but I didn't find any setting for the web filtering there.So I tried to download the latest iPhone Configuration Utility App for the purpose and found that apple has removed this from their page.So I am unable to find a way how to do it. Can somebody please suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Nobosi is close but it's missing something key. Web Filtering can only be implemented via device supervision. The only two ways to supervise a device are through Apple Configurator or via Apple's DEP (device enrollment program) in conjunction with an MDM.

There are obviously benefits and detractors to each solution.

Apple Configurator

- (+) Free
- (+) Easy to setup
- (-) Changes require re-tethering the device
- (-) Devices should be tethered once per year due to cert expirations

MDM (AirWatch, MobileIron, etc)

- (+) Easy to maintain OTA (over the air)
- (+) highly versatile configuration and management options
- (-) going to cost you some money to implement (licensing, etc)
- (-) DEP requires buying devices directly from Apple or a DEP-enabled reseller

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above Web filtering can only be done in supervised device. MDMs provide this feature. Speaking from experience, Hexnode MDM provides a fair option for web filtering. There is option for black listing and white listing URLs. You can black list the URLs and prevent access to these sites or you can white list URLs and provide access to only these sites.
Also in iOS there is option to restrict inappropriate content. Hexnode MDM provides an option to enable access to these restricted sites by entering the URL of the "said" restricted site and make it an exception.